# Is spacecraft propulsion observable in space?

Tags: engines, physics, exhaust

There are questions on this site about [minimal sound in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23851/where-does-the-noise-on-spacewalks-come-from). But I was very surprised by Russell Borogove's answer to "[Why did the Saturn V stage faring appear to burn after separation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/why-did-the-saturn-v-stage-fairing-appear-to-burn-after-separation/)" that ["hydrogen-oxygen exhaust is essentially clear"](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18057/22581).

Without visible and audible evidence...is spacecraft exhaust even observable in space? I suspect it still has an infrared heat signature or something. This paints a very different picture than most movie depictions of spacecraft maneuvering in space.

Comment: See also https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20268/195

Comment: "The Expanse" and some other modern visual media actually do a fair job of this -- the main engines give off a blue glow suggestive of hydrogen combustion and the attitude thrusters give off white puffs similar to what's seen when e.g. the space shuttle manuevers.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ewbD2Pv5ag

Comment: While the question may overlap with Organic Marble's question, the answer in Russell Borogove's link was more satisfactory to my misunderstanding. Both were useful. Thank you.

Comment: Most exhaust from upper stages is (more or less by coincidence) clear. Additional the big clouds of smoke and steam at the beginning of a launch is usually from SRBs and water to protect the pads, both of which are usually not used in space (except as kick motors for satellites). However RCS thruster exhaust [is clearly visible](https://youtu.be/scGc1NS_IV8?t=3m52s) while docking and very prominent in ISS cargo and crew launches.